# Posting data from url by using Poll Mule

Tags: xml, mule, polling, anypoint-studio

I have generated a service for posting data into my Database. I want to setup a timer then at every 19th minute past every hour. For doing this, i have used Poll scope in Mule ( i am doing project in Mule). Unfortunately, i got this error when i run the Mule:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'poll'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context":property-placeholder, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":ref, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":global-property, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":configuration, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":notifications, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-extension, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-extension, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-extension, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-agent, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-security-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-transaction-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-transaction-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-connector, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-connector, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-global-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-exception-strategy, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-flow-construct, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":flow, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":sub-flow, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-model, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-interceptor-stack, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-filter, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-transformer, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":processor-chain, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":custom-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-empty-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":invoke, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-global-intercepting-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":custom-queue-store, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-processing-strategy}' is expected.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.
```

Please help me to figure out this problem, thank you so much. Here is my mule configuration xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:schedulers="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/schedulers" xmlns:dynamicscrm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/dynamicscrm" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms"
    xmlns:test="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/test" xmlns:jbossts="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jbossts"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jersey="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.6.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey/current/mule-jersey.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jbossts http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jbossts/current/mule-jbossts.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/test http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/test/current/mule-test.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/dynamicscrm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/dynamicscrm/current/mule-dynamicscrm.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/schedulers http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/schedulers/current/mule-schedulers.xsd">

    <spring:beans>
        <spring:import resource="classpath:spring/spring-config.xml" />
    </spring:beans>

    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
        host="10.16.52.222" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" />
    <poll doc:name="Poll">
            <schedulers:cron-scheduler expression="19 * * * *"/>
     <processor-chain>
        <set-payload value="#[['xxx':'yyy']]" />
         <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://10.16.52.222:8081/test" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        </processor-chain>
    </poll>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `poll` needs to be within a `flow`

```
<flow name="myFlow">
 <poll doc:name="Poll">
     <schedulers:cron-scheduler expression="19 * * * *"/>
     <processor-chain>
        <set-payload value="#[['xxx':'yyy']]" />
         <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://10.16.52.222:8081/test" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
     </processor-chain>
 </poll>
 <logger />
</flow>
```